# TortoiseSVN Error: "OPTIONS of 'https://...' could not connect to server (...)"

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to setup a new computer to synchronize with my SVN repository that's hosted with cvsdude.com.

I get this error:

![SVN Error][1] - *removed image shack image that had been replaced by an advert*

Here's what I did (these have worked in the past):

1. Downloaded and installed TortoiseSVN
2. Created a new folder C:\aspwebsite
3. Right-clicked, chose SVN Checkout...
4. Entered the following information, clicked OK:

   - URL of repository: https://<reponame>-svn.cvsdude.com/aspwebsite
   - Checkout directory: C:\aspwebsite
   - Checkout depth: Fully recursive
   - Omit externals: Unchecked
   - Revision: HEAD revision
5. Got TortoiseSVN error:

   - OPTIONS of 'https://<reponame>-svn.cvsdude.com/aspwebsite': could not connect to server (https://<reponame>-svn.cvsdude.com)

Rather than getting the error, TortoiseSVN should have asked for my username and password and then downloaded about 90MB.

Why can't I checkout from my Subversion repository?

---

> [Kent Fredric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15614/kent-fredric) wrote:
>
> Either their security certificate has
>   expired, or their hosting is
>   broken/down.
>
> Contact CVSDude and ask them whats up.
>
> It could also be a timeout, because
>   for me their site is *exhaustively*
>   slow..

It errors after only a couple seconds. I don't think it's a timeout.

> [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2590/matt) wrote:
>
> Try visiting
>   https://[redacted]-svn.cvsdude.com/aspwebsite
>   and see what happens. If you can visit
>   it in your browser, you ought to be
>   able to get the files in your SVN
>   client and we can work from there. If
>   it fails, then there's your answer.

I can access the site in a web browser.

Comment: Where you refer to <reponame> you probably mean <account name>. At least, this is the way CVSDude structures their URL's.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Your image link seems to have broken. If you still have the original image, please reupload it to stack.imgur. Or, perhaps better yet, just type out the text of the error.

Answer (score 37):

Check you proxy settings in **TortoiseSVN->Settings->Network**.

Maybe they are configured differently than in your web browser.

Comment: Note also that some proxys (such as the one in my office) don't support SVN use through them without some sort of manual configuration.  More information is available on their website, iirc.

Comment: +1, I was getting this with Codeplex svn and it turned out to be the Tortoise proxy settings.

Comment: Worth pointing out that much of this thread is not specific to TortoiseSVN. I just had the same error on the SVN command line on OSX. The ridiculously unhelpful message ("svn: OPTIONS of" - really??) hides the fact that you need to set proxy settings specifically for SVN (even if they're in the system network preferences).

Comment: This was very likely, but actually didn't Tortoise/Subclipse when Internet Explorer can browse normally...

Answer (score 27):

Late reaction, but I've struggled with this for a while so maybe I can save somebody some time by showing my solution.

My problem showed a bit different, but the cause might be the same.

In my situation, TortoiseSVN kept on trying to connect via a proxy server. I could access SVN via chrome, firefox and IE fine.

Turns out that there is a **configuration file** that has a different configuration than the GUI in TortoiseSVN shows.

Mine was located here:
`C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Application Data\Subversion\`, but you can also open the file via the TortoiseSVN gui.

[image: TortoiseSVN]

In my file, `http-proxy-exceptions was empty`. After I specified it, everything worked fine.

```
[global]
http-proxy-exceptions = 10.1.1.11
http-proxy-host = 197.132.0.223
http-proxy-port = 8080
http-proxy-username = defaultusername
http-proxy-password = defaultpassword
http-compression = no
```

Comment: You are my hero @Wouter van Nifterick:)

Answer (score 14):

I realize this is an old question, but the same issue happened to me, but for a completely different reason.

It could be that cvs-dude changed certificates, so it no longer matches the certificate you have cached.

You can go to **TortoiseSVN->Settings->Saved Data** and click the 'Clear' button next to 'Authentication data' and then try again.

Answer (score 8):

This was driving me nuts and I solved it today.  I'm posting in this old thread because I arrived here several times while searching for a solution.  I hope it helps someone.
For me, I checked svn-settings --> network --> Edit Subversion server file and found that there were some uncommented lines at the end:

```
http-proxy-host = 
ssl-trust-default-ca = no
http-proxy-username = 
http-proxy-password =
```

that differed from my co-workers.  Once I comment these, it started working again.

Comment: I found a file called "server" in C:\Users\All Users\Subversion\. I The file contain the same contents you have in your answer. Deleting this file resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Mannn thanks a lot. I've just comment this lines and my problem has gone. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you are almost definitely behind a proxy server.

Where this does ***not*** work for me behind my proxy:

```
svn checkout http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ v8-read-only
```

this ***does***:

```
svn --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-host=MY_PROXY_HOST --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-port=MY_PROXY_PORT checkout http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ v8-read-only
```

**UPDATE** I forgot to quote my source :-)

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07.html#svn-ch-7-sect-1.3.1

Answer (score 4):

I just had a similar issue, but it didn't error immediately, so it may have not been the same issue.

I'm behind a firewall and changed my proxy settings (TortoiseSVN->Settings->Network) to access an open source repo yesterday.  I received the error this morning trying to checkout a repo in the local domain behind the firewall.  I just had to remove the proxy settting in TortoiseSVN->Settings->Network to get it work locally again.

Answer (score 2):

It is the problem with your proxy setting in TortoiseSVN. Connect using a network which doesn't use proxy or configure your proxy settings properly.

Answer (score 1):

Either their security certificate has expired, or their hosting is broken/down.

Contact CVSDude and ask them whats up.

It could also be a timeout, because for me their site is *exhaustively* slow..

Comment: It errors after only a couple seconds.  I don't think it's a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I've have the same problem like this, but using my own server. Maybe APACHE is allowing only limited connection to the same server. I'm increasing the max_connection and KeepAlive setting. So far so good.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue; turns out it was case-sensitivity issue. So, make sure you use the proper case.

Comment: Case sensitive of what? The server name in a URL is not case sensitive (but the path is)

Answer (score 1):

Try pasting in the SVN URL into your browser's Address bar. You'll likely see that you cannot connect because of some issue with the URL. I had this issue just today and the problem was that I had mistyped the port number, but as others have noted it could also be a case-sensitivity issue, proxy settings, or other connection-level issues.

Answer (score 1):

I did not have network settings changed in any way and thus most of the stuff presented here did not apply to me. After messing around a lot the comment about the virus scanner got me on the right track: There are some virus scanners like McAfee, that protect certain areas of the system directories and make them read-only.
When you connect to a server for the first time, Tortoise SVN tries to write the certificate on one of these files which fails due to the protection. Switch off the protection briefly, start the check out and after the certificate dialog, you can switch it back on. This at least worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error today and discovered that the firewall was blocking the svn client

Answer (score 1):

This can occur because of you are trying to checking out the repository by accessing it via a proxy server without enabling the proxy server in the place you need to change the settings in TortoiseSvn. So if you are using a proxy server make sure that you put a tick in "Enable Proxy Server" in Settings->Network and give your Server address and Port number in the relevant places. Now try to check out again.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to all the commenters on this page. When I first installed the latest TortoiseSVN I got this error.

I was using the latest version, so decided to downgrade to 1.5.9 (as the rest of my colleagues were using) and this got it to work. Then, once built, my machine was moved onto another subnet and the problem started again.

I went to TortoiseSVN->Settings->Saved Data and cleared the Authentication data. After this it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

make sure when you add your proxy entries to the server file, you add them under the [global] group. (That seemed to make the difference for me under ubuntu.)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error too when I had my server as an exception for the proxy in the SVN config file like this: `http-proxy-exceptions = *.repo.domain.com`

The solution for me was to use the svn server IP instead of the name. For some reason the name was not getting properly resolved from Eclipse Juno - Subclipse and from TortoiseSVN.

So, what worked for me: `http-proxy-exceptions = XXX.XX.X.X` (the server IP)

Comment: I solvet it adding the http-proxy-exceptions = ...  Tks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

For me [this was the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15531448/442580).

The problem was that the SVN server was behind a reverse-proxy (pound). And the reverse proxy had to be told to allow `OPTIONS`.

Answer (score 0):

remote VisualSVN server 2.5.8 is accessible from at least 3 computers. 
However on my local computer the url of the repository was not accessible 
and `svn ls https://server-ip:443/svn/project/trunk` return error

```
OPTIONS of 'https://…' could not connect to server (…)
```

My local computer used to have access to the server. The only thing that was changed was switching to http connection instead of https for Redmine reasons(certificate issue).

I tried different things listed above. What actually solved my problem was installing a new the `VisualSVN server 2.5.9` using the same repository. And also Redmine recognized the new repository through https.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the answers resolved the issue for me. Even after I had installed a new version of Tortoise SVN + Ccleaner.

Seems that there is a folder in `AppData\Roaming\Subversion` that contains all configuration of Tortoise SVN. You need to delete it all and restart Tortoise SVN.

Hope this helps someone as the ultimate solution.