# Accessing svn repo wtih TortoiseSVN from work vs. home + VPN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I get the same error described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111543/tortoisesvn-error-options-of-https-could-not-connect-to-server) other SO post. The difference is that things are working when I'm at work where I don't have to VPN to the network. But when I try to access the same exact SVN repo from home I get the following error:

> TortoiseSVN Error: “OPTIONS of ‘https://…’ could not connect to server (…)”

This was never a problem until recently when I upgraded to the latest TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN builds. I should also mention that at the time of the upgraded I made Chrome my default browser but not sure if this has anything to do with it.

I've sense reverted TortoiseSVN to the previous build and switched my default browser back to IE but I'm still unable to connect to the repo from home.

Comment: Test access with FF/IE using RDP to internal server and verify

Answer (score 1):

Since you're connecting through Subversion via Apache httpd, you could open a browser and type in the https:// URL you're trying to checkout. This will eliminate the Subversion client on your end, and let you know if the issue is with the client or not.

If you can't access the URL via the browser, the problem is with either the connection or the server side. If you can access the same URL from work, then the problem is with the connection.

If the problem is with your connection, you'll have to talk to your IT department about the issue. Can you reach any other internal website via your browser over the VPN? Is it just this particular server? HTTPS uses port 443 instead of the default port 80. It is very likely that your IT department in a fit of *[security overload](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/05/20/technology/personaltech/20pogue-email.html)* has decided to block almost all ports except for port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access the svn repository through your browser? As well as testing the connection that should tell you if there are any certificate issues to be dealt with.

Comment: I'm unable to access the svn repo through the browser.

Answer (score 0):

- Have you verified that the VPN for you're work connects you inside the corporate network?
- Can you do anything that you could do at work like access file shares on internal servers or access development servers?
- Please supply exact error from your IE/FF when navigating to the VisualSVN URL.

Ok, so you cannot access the SVN repository thru your browser which narrows the problem down to either networking configuration (proxy server, firewall) or the server will only allow access from specific IP addresses.

- Can you RDP to a server in the workplace and verify access to the HTTPS site via the browser is successfull? If this fails, can you verify that VisualSVN is running?

Comment: Good question and yes I can do all that. Sorry I should have mentioned that in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to set the proxy. Upgrading Tortoise versions would unset the proxy, and changing browsers would do the same browser-side. I get the same error through vpn when I forget to set the proxy.