# Can we checkout from SVN repository using web based application?

Tags: svn

Currently I am hosting my open source project in Google Code. And they provide SVN repository using `svn`. But, unfortunately my company here I think wouldn't allow me to access to svn other than Company Project (offcourse they are).

How do I checkout from my project on Google Code, with this limitation? that is, I can not use command line `svn` or Tortoise Subversion???

Many thanks.

Comment: What is the limitation? is it technical (port blocking) or contractual (your boss told you not to do it)?

Comment: Each language has its own API for svn, ie : http://svnkit.com/ . Just amend your web-app. Or could you install a webdav for your repo ?

Comment: @charlesB port blocking. The command display message more or less like this : `cannot resolve to code.google.com`. But if I open remote SVN repository that is our company project, it run just fine

Comment: Are you sure it is port blocking? If you use http access it should be on port 80, so I doubt this port is blocked. Do you have access to code.google.com website?

Comment: No. the port blocking is when I use `svn` command line utilities. Off course I can use Web and open code.google.com. Because of that, I am thinking of checking out code.google.com using web application. Is there any>

Comment: svn through http (which is the way you checkout project on google code) uses port 80. there must be another problem, can you post the command used to checkout? do you use `svn checkout http://xxx.com`?

Comment: Also when answering to a comment put @username in it so that he gets notified (I don't need it in my comment since you get notified anyway as the question owner)

Comment: Are you sure it's not a corporate proxy that's blocking it?

Comment: @CharlesB yes, btw, this is my project checkout page : http://code.google.com/p/recite18th/source/checkout So i supply the command `svn checkout https://recite18th.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ recite18th --username swdev.bali@gmail.com` And this is the message `svn: OPTIONS of 'https://recite18th.googlecode.com/svn/trunk': could not connect
 to server (https://recite18th.googlecode.com)`

By the way, I just found actually the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111543/tortoisesvn-error-options-of-https-could-not-connect-to-server

Comment: @DaveShaw Yes, I think it's the proxy configuration. And somehow, I dunno how to figure out the solution...

Comment: Try with http instead of https?

Comment: @CharlesB No :) Could not connect to server also...

Comment: TSVN Allows you to enter proxy settings but depending on the proxy/network config the credentials are not always passed through, I remeber someone showing me a complicated setup to allow it, I can try and find out if you need it.

Comment: @DaveShaw. Yes Dave, that should be very helpful to me. I recommend you put it in answer section, and not in comment section like this, so I can accept your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: I believe it's not port blocking, instead DNS query filtering...

Comment: I'll ask the guy who helped me last time tomorrow and post what he says.

Comment: @DaveShaw : Thanks dave! Currently, I do the commit to my project outside company network. That is the easiest solution:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Configure TortoiseSVN so that it uses the right proxy (Server address and Port are self-explaining, username is `domain\username`, Password is your domain login pass)
2. Simply do Tortoise -> SVN Checkout and enter the URL that you can find on the **Source** tab of your project on code.google.com.

*If that doesn't help you:* maybe you could clone your google SVN repo into a Git repo when being outside the corporate network (using [`git svn clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn)) and work on that Git repo while being at work (the Git repo could be on an external HD, for example). When you're done take the HD home and replay the changes from your Git repo on the HD back to google code (`git svn dcommit`).

When you do some work at home and committed it to google code, pull in these changes into your Git repo by doing `git svn rebase`. If you do that often enough, you'll end up asking yourself *what do I need SVN and a central server for?*

Comment: This is very self explaining...
Offer the idea to synch two repo
I want to accept it as the answer, but I should try this first.

Comment: I haven't had time to apply the solution, but this is the best (for my opinion). I'll takt this as answer. Many thanks.

Comment: I wish I could +100 this answer. Mostly for: what do I need SVN and a central server for?

Comment: Wait a minute... I thought by just accepting the answer, you already got my bounty? isn't that the case? but I recognize you only got half the bounty... I am sorry. What is the proper way to give bounty anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Try to run this on your machine:

```
nslookup code.google.com
```

If it's says the same (cannot resolve), most probably your company filters out UDP packets for name server lookup (DNS query) for domains other than what they allow.

If that's the case, too bad then.

I tried to workaround by accessing direct IP address after nslookup gave response, but seems it doesn't work. Probably Google Code's server has this virtual server that depends on the server name code.google.com to determine which services we are aiming for.

Comment: It says this : `
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.212.0.102

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    code.l.google.com
Addresses:  74.125.235.43
          74.125.235.35
          74.125.235.46
          74.125.235.40
          74.125.235.37
          74.125.235.44
          74.125.235.39
          74.125.235.38
          74.125.235.42
          74.125.235.32
          74.125.235.47
          74.125.235.41
          74.125.235.33
          74.125.235.36
          74.125.235.34
          74.125.235.45
Aliases:  code.google.com`

Comment: So, I think ... there's no problem then?

Comment: OK. Then it's not DNS lookup query. Can you open this link from the browser? https://recite18th.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Answer (score 2):

In the past I have used [NTLM Aps](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/) to pass through the NTLM authentication to the proxy server because TSVN doesn't.

IIRC we proxy TSVN (no auth) to the NTLM Aps and then proxy the NTLM Aps to out corporate one using our NTLM credentials.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me check on that link first, and report  you the result. Seems promising :)