# subversion eclipse and multiple repositories

Tags: eclipse, svn, pycharm

i have a fun svn problem. With eclipse, i have the svn plugin, and that works all well and good. Or did, until a few days ago, when i setup a repo on a remote server for a different project (on a remote server because i'm sharing code with another developer. The local svn repo is for my own projects).

Pycharm... oh pycharm. Let's not worry about that odd ball app for now, but rest assured that the new repo works fine.

Problem is, i just tried to commit some code using my svn eclipse, and what does it say?

> svn: Commit failed (details follow):
>   svn: OPTIONS of 'http://localhost/svn/projectA/app/views/pages': Could not resolve hostname `svn://x.y.z.a/projectB.': The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
>    (http://localhost)

Now, my projectA (local, private work) used to happily sit at http://localhost/projectA (or something. I don't really know where it used to sit anymore, how do i find this out?)
Stupid projectB seems to have taken over the *entire* svn committing process (unsure how). How can i tell eclipse or svn or whatever that for projectA code, use one repository? And then, for projectB, i have pycharm using the *other* repository?

UPDATE:
i tried:

```
svn switch --relocate svn://x.y.z.a/projectA/ http://localhost/projectB
```

this didn't do anything at all - well, i still get the same error. I might have the old svn location of projectB wrong, can i find this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah.

I see what happened - I do not know HOW it happened, but in case it does, it is a subversion thing, not an eclipse thing.

check this answer out on a similar thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246140/1061426

(i chose this one because, well, it lets you find where the  svn repository is!)
(and by that i mean, when the file pops up, just run a save-as to see where the file is!)

(in case you do not have tortoise, here is where  the  repo is on windows 7:

```
C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Roaming\Subversion
```

)

Answer (score 1):

Check the general /network options (between direct, manual or proxy). If you need to setup proxy parameters, you will have to make sure the no_proxy is set to include localhost, in order for *both* repos to work.

Regarding the address of your second repository, you could check it with a command-line like svn info.