# Make a new svn repository for my project

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

This is going to be a pretty dumb question, but heeeere we go:

I have a project . It is on subversion. Svn blew up big time, and i do not care to keep the code in the repository. It is only me working on the code, and my code is pretty ace.

Also, my poor laptop is v.v. Close to becoming a flying laptop.

So!

The project is in folder C:somwhere on my windows machine.
I want to - and i think i have, removed the project and killed all the svn files - at least, that is what eclipse assures me.

What i want to do is to

1. Create a new svn repo for this project, it can be anywhere
2. Put the code in folder c:somewhere into this new repo
3. That. Is. It.

Sso how do i do this? My svn connection is currently http:localhost/svn/Bodymap, i would like it to be http:localhost/svn/healosophy - do i need to make the repo in some fancy location? If so, how would i find where the location is?

Thanks!

UPDAAAAAAATE: [How do I locate the SVN repository directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658461/how-do-i-locate-the-svn-repository-directory)

The above is my follow-up question, which let me find where the old repo was located. This in itself isn't important - you can make a repo anywhere, right?
However, the answer given also tells you that the repo location is defined in the apache httpd.conf. This is a good way to find the repo and - and this is the key - also change where the apache server looks for the new repo. In my case, i updated the svnpath to point to where i wanted my new location to be.

Finally, check out this answer here for probably issues your svn setup will have if you start changing where it points. As far as i can see, it boils down to "proxy settings with subversion are bad, don't use them".

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9648449/1061426

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an svn repository with `svnadmin create C:/Foo/Bar`

Then put your source in it with `svn import C:/Old/Path file:///C:/Foo/Bar`