# How do I locate the SVN repository directory?

Tags: svn

I know where the URL (`localhost/svn/BodyMap/`) is, but I do not know which folder it is in my Windows 7 setup.

It should be a standard SVN setup, if that helps - I don't recall doing anything "clever" with it.

I suppose what I mean is, I have code X. Code X is in the SVN, um, system. You know, I've committed code X there. Presumably, at some time in the past I ran an `svnadmin` command to create that location so SVN knew to put the code (or whatever) there.

I guess I'm asking - given the URL to get to a repository location, how would I find the location of the repository (the thing that was made with the `svnadmin create` command) that relates to that given URL?

Assuming that everything is my local Windows machine

Check out this page:

```
http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/version-control-with-subversion-1.6/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.create.html
```

I have a repository, I am using Apache, and I have everything setup. I now want to make another repository (long story). I would, ideally, like to have the new repository in the same folder/area as the old one.

I have no idea *where* the old one is - I mean, I must have gone to, say, `C:/users/bhral/svn` or something, and typed in the `svnadmin create` command? So how do I find out where that "there" is? Is there a configuration file somewhere that remembers this?

`svn info` in the directory of the shared code gives:

```
Path: .
URL: http://localhost/svn/BodyMap
Repository Root: http://localhost/svn
Repository UUID: a26120f9-5528-1345-ada7-6086a2d5766d
Revision: 1
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Depth: immediates
Last Changed Rev: 1
Last Changed Date: 2010-12-18 19:23:40 -0500 (Sat, 18 Dec 2010)
```

Does that mean that the repository is in the same location as the code? Or rather, that the "remote" location is in the same place as the "client" code?

Update on URL:

```
localhost/svn/BodyMap/
```

Comment: i use tortoise,  when i right click on a directory i get the option to "checkout".  this would be your directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your repository is served by Apache (because for `svn://` picture differ), you have to

- Find your Apache configuration (httpd.conf)
- Locate the `Location` container inside the configuration file with SVN WebDAV `DAV svn`
- Identify method, used for defining repository location: it can be SVNPath or SVNParentPath directives
- In case of `SVNPath` the repository is placed directly on the path, defined as SVNPath parameter
- In case of `SVNParentPath` it lists **parent-path** to all repositories

**ADD-ON: "Light" version**

```
d:\Repositories\Hello>dir /b
conf
dav
db
format
hooks
locks
README.txt
```

You can search for any repository-specific file or folder in Explorer ("hooks" is good candidate).

Comment: You can also try to check if there's a VisualSVN Server installed on the server machine which hosts the repository (in case it's a windows platform)

Answer (score 8):

`svn info` will probably point you there. I don't totally understand what you're asking though.

Answer (score 3):

- If the URL is `file://C:\Path\to\repository` then the path is
  `C:\Path\to\repository`.

Comment: Without -1, just note - for Apache-based repo answer is wrong. Just wrong, totally