# svn support on reverse proxy (pound) OPTIONS authorization failed

Tags: reverse-proxy

How do I implement the WebDav support on [pound](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pound)?

Error:

> svn: OPTIONS of "[repo] "authorization failed"

I can't find any examples. What I have gives me `unknown directive`

```
ListenHTTPS
        Address 192.168.1.200
        Port 443
        Cert "/etc/pound/server.pem"
        WebDav 1
        HTTPSHeaders 1 "Front-End-Https: on"'

        Service
                HeadRequire "Host: .*svn.mydomain.com.*"
                BackEnd
                        Address 192.168.1.21
                        Port    80
                End
        End
        Service
                HeadRequire "Host: .*svn.mydomain.org.*"
                BackEnd
                        Address 192.168.1.21
                        Port    80
                End
        End
End
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution `xHTTP 2`

```
ListenHTTPS
        Address 192.168.1.200
        Port 443
        Cert "/etc/pound/server.pem"

        xHTTP 2

        Service
        ...
```

From `man pound` (*who knew manuals had useful information?*):

```
xHTTP value
              Defines which HTTP verbs are accepted. The possible values are:
              ...
              2  additionally  allow  standard WebDAV verbs (LOCK, UNLOCK, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, SEARCH, MKCOL, MOVE, COPY, OPTIONS, TRACE, MKACTIVITY, CHECKOUT, MERGE, REPORT).
               ...
```